# No goals have been specified for this build. You must specify a valid lifecycle phase

Tags: java, docker, maven, github-actions

I keep getting the error from the title while trying to push to docker via GitHub Actions. I have a Java Maven application.
When I build and push the docker image manually everything works but it does not work automatically via GitHub Actions as specified in the title.

Here is my workflow action:

```
 name: Docker Image CI

on:
  workflow_dispatch:
  push:
    branches: [ main ]
  pull_request:
    branches: [ main ]

jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@v2
    - name: Set up JDK 8
      uses: actions/setup-java@v1
      with:
        java-version: 8
    - name: Setup the POM file
      run: mvn -f app-demo/pom.xml 
    - name: Build with Maven
      run: mvn clean install dependency:copy-dependencies
    - name: Login to GitHub Package Registry
      run: echo ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }} | docker login docker.pkg.github.com -u ${{ github.repository }} --password-stdin
    - name: Build the Docker image
      run: docker build -t app-demo:latest .
    - name: Tag the Docker image
      run: docker tag app-demo:latest docker.pkg.github.com/repo/app-demo/app-demo:latest
    - name: Push the Docker image to the registry
      run: docker push docker.pkg.github.com/repo/app-demo/app-demo:latest
```

Here is my POM file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.4.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.app.demo</groupId>
    <artifactId>app-demo</artifactId>
    <version>latest</version>
    <name>acs-simulator</name>
    <description>APP Demo</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>8</java.version>
    </properties>




    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-logging</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
            <artifactId>aws-lambda-java-core</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-configuration-processor</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                    <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.hivemq</groupId>
            <artifactId>hivemq-mqtt-client</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.1</version>
        </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.fasterxml.jackson.core/jackson-databind -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
            <version>2.11.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-log4j2</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.hivemq</groupId>
            <artifactId>hivemq-testcontainer-junit5</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter-engine</artifactId>
            <version>5.6.1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter-api</artifactId>
            <version>5.6.1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
            <artifactId>mockito-all</artifactId>
            <version>1.10.19</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.paho</groupId>
            <artifactId>org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.5</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
                <version> 3.2.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <createDependencyReducedPom>false</createDependencyReducedPom>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>shade</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>


</project>
```

What do I have this error and how do I solve it? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Why do you use maven-shade-plugin in a Spring Boot app? Why defining JUnit Jupiter version yourself? Why defining mockito-all versions yourself ?All versions are handled by the spring boot parent... also I would suggest to upgrade your spring boot version to the most recent one (2.4.2) ... also Jackson is defined by spring boot parent ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is this, I think:

```
- name: Setup the POM file
  run: mvn -f app-demo/pom.xml 
- name: Build with Maven
  run: mvn clean install dependency:copy-dependencies
```

The first `run:` is running maven without any goals.  You need a single run ... like this:

```
- name: Build with Maven
  run: mvn -f app-demo/pom.xml clean install dependency:copy-dependencies
```

Either way, check the [Maven documentation](https://books.sonatype.com/mvnref-book/reference/running.html) to understand what the `mvn` command line arguments mean.